# How do I highlight a country with the google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to this:

[image: http://www.state.gov/cms_images/france_map_2007-worldfactbook2.jpg]

Notice how France is brighter than the other countries. It has the 'focus'. I've been exploring the API and it looks like I'm supposed use `kmlLayers` to achieve this effect. Is this correct? If so, how do I leverage or even find kml to do this? How else could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found this can be done with polygons and 'holes'. Google has [this pentagon example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/pentagon.html)

The only down side is the polygon needs to be drawn by hand (maybe there's a database of country outlines?) I used [this tool](http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html) to assist with the manual drawing for now.

Answer (score 2):

The information at these links will help you, I think:

1. KML of the [World Countries](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/gec-tools/rNjNRYbaWSI/5x5vfgxc0w0J) as created by Valery Hronusov
2. KML of the [World Capitals](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/gec-tools/wYh3esMW6XM/XNcwYwlTuB0J) as created by Filipumme

Answer (score 1):

this demo shows you how: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

aight, got kml for france; working demo: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/maps/gmaps/layer-kml-02.html

Comment: thanks. My issue with this was that it's a reverse from what I need (I have no way of hiding the other countries, just France in this case). Also, for some reason the kml data has many unfilled regions.